# Socket.BeginReceive freezes on a high load when non blocking send used (TCP)

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I have 2 connected to server clients. Each is sending and receiving around 1 mb per second. Sometimes the server socket.BeginReceive freezes on a 200-300 ms.
 SendBufferSize = 20 bytes. Yes, it's not a correct value for such traffic. But it shouldn't be the cause for receive freezing. 
If I set a bigger SendBufferSize value (1000) the freezes disappear.
It would be hard to extract it from my code to reproduce. But can you guess what could be the possible cause for such **async receive** freezes?

Comment: You should set the send buffer size to several dozen kilobytes *at least,* otherwise you're just wasting the network's and CPU's time. The question therefore lacks general interest.

Comment: @EJP There is a possible critical vulnerability for server if any client can make the server async IO methods block. So it should have an attention at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is doesn't freezes: sometimes it completes synchronously so it takes a time to process the received data. Now I check IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously property and call QueueUserWorkItem if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your packet size is so small, you're almost certainly running into [Nagle's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). Somewhere deep in the network stack, your data is being buffered so it can be combined into larger, more sensibly sized packets to prevent network congestion. You can switch it off by supplying TCP_NODELAY to your socket with the [Socket.NoDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, but given that TCP packet headers can be 40bytes long, that's a lot of overhead.

Perhaps UDP might make more sense for your application.

Comment: No, I set NoDelay = true

Comment: Your 1mb/s might cost up to 3mb/s with such small packets. Is your network up to this?

Comment: I test on a loopback. May be not. But can it affect **async** IO method so it **freezes**?

Comment: @Vlad: I think you should take some time to make a short working example of the problem, otherwise it's like shooting in the dark.